# Can I omit "should" at this time?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, phrases, expressions

> By the end of the week, all applicants (should) have a preliminary interview.

So, is the right sentence...?

> By the end of the week, all applicants have a preliminary interview.
> *or*
> By the end of the week, she have a preliminary interview.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the intended meaning. The initial sentence can omit `should` but the meaning changes.

> By the end of the week, all applicants should have a preliminary interview

Means the expectation<sup>1</sup> is for all applicants to have an interview

> By the end of the week, all applicants have a preliminary interview

Means all applicants have an interview scheduled. Adding `scheduled` at the end of the sentence would clarify the meaning further.

---

> By the end of the week, she have a preliminary interview

Does not make sense as `she` is 3rd person so [`have` in 3rd person should be `has`](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/have)

> By the end of the week, she has a preliminary interview.

<sub>1 [shall](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shall)</sub>

Comment: OP might actually mean “... all applicants should have had a preliminary interview.”   I think more context is needed.

Comment: I agree; I'm not so sure that "All applicants have an interview scheduled by the end of the week" is really a logical construction. The hearer interprets "by" as "between now and," but it's really an expression of a deadline.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the parentheses in the original quote. I think you've interpreted these to mean that the word "should" is grammatically redundant in the sentence and could be removed, but I don't think that's what's intended. I suspect the original writer intended a shortening of "By the end of the week, all applicants will have a preliminary interview (or at least, they *should*)."